# How to set env variables using ASDF in a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables, asdf-vm

Rbenv uses `rbenv-vars` to specify per-application environment variables in Rails.

Most version managers read the `.env` file in every project for the environment variables.

However, I can't find a way to make [asdf-vm](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby) and [asdf-ruby](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-ruby) to read the `.env` file and export all the env variables in there (or any file with the env variables).

The docs on the same are quite scanty.

How do you set environment variables using `asdf-vm` or `asdf-ruby` on a Rails project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin [asdf-vars](https://github.com/excid3/asdf-vars) for this. The env file is called `.asdf-vars` and functions the same as a `.rbenv-vars` file.

As of writing this, you will need to modify `asdf`'s `command-exec.bash` file to get the plugin to work. There is a discussion [here](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/367) about making the process easier.